# Convert date format in csv by powershell

Tags: datetime, powershell, csv

I have the .csv file using 'MM DD YYYY HH:MM:SS' time format

Can I use the powershell convert to 'MMM DD, YYYY HH:MM:SS TT' ?

data.csv
09 17 2014 00:05:00,69.07217
09 17 2014 01:05:00,637.1816
09 17 2014 02:05:00,0.0
09 17 2014 03:05:00,481.296

I would like to ....
Sep 17, 2014 00:05:00 AM,69.07217
Sep 17, 2014 01:05:00 AM,637.1816
Sep 17, 2014 02:05:00 AM,0.0
Sep 17, 2014 03:05:00 AM,481.296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$dateTime = '09 17 2014 00:05:00'
"{0:MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss tt}" -f [DateTime]::ParseExact($dateTime, 'MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
```

Outputs:

```
Sep 17, 2014 00:05:00 AM
```

Although if you want AM/PM shouldn't you use the 12-hour clock e.g. `hh`?

Comment: Sorry about, the data file is daily file, can the $dateTime dynamic variable?

Comment: That's the whole point of a `vari-able`.  :-) You can assign to the $dateTime the various date fields you read from the CSV file.